# System.JSONException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value

Tags: apex, json, jsongenerator

Im struggling with JSON generator for making a HTTP request

```
    public String zendeskCalloutManager(string description, string keyToVerify){

    // define a response to caller
    String outcomeMsg;

    // define the body for PUT request
    String bodyLine1 = 'Hai Pak/Bu,';
    String bodyLine2 = 'Sudah hampir 24 jam semenjak kami terakhir mendengar dari Bapak/Ibu, Secara system, tiket ini akan otomatis dianggap selesai jika tidak ada respon kembali dari anda.';
    String bodyLine3 = 'Jika Bapak/Ibu masih membutuhkan konfirmasi/bantuan dari kami, harap membalas YA pada pesan ini atau silahkan menghubungi kami kembali kapanpun di masa depan.';
    String bodyLine4 = 'Terimakasih';
    String bodyAllLine = '"' + bodyLine1 + '\r\n' + bodyLine2 + '\r\n' + bodyLine3 + '\r\n' + bodyLine4 + '"';
    String data_comment = '{"ticket":{"comment": {"body":' + bodyAllLine + '}}}';
    //JSONParser bodyParser = JSON.createParser(data_comment);

    // Set the request parameters
    String endpoint_get = 'https://propertypro.zendesk.com/api/v2/search.json?'; // be sure this is configured in "Remote Site Settings"
    String resource_get = 'query=type%3Aticket+tags%3Atest_python';
    String endpoint_put ='https://propertypro.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/update_many.json?' +'ids=';
    String resource_put = '4249'; 
    String username = 'mart.polman@lamudi.co.id'; 
    String password = 'lamudionfire';
    String method_get = 'GET';
    String method_put = 'PUT'; 

    // check to ensure a callout can be performed using the Limits class. 
    // This is 100 callouts per execution as of Spring 16 release
    if (Limits.getCallouts() >= Limits.getLimitCallouts()) {
        outcomeMsg = 'Maximum number of callouts has been reached.';

    // check for credentials error
    } else if (endpoint_get == null || username == null || password == null) {
        outcomeMsg = 'Please verify your API Credentials';

    // configure and perform the callout
    } else {

        // define transaction variables for GET request
        HttpRequest req_get = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res_get = new HttpResponse();
        Http h_get = new Http();

        // Configure the get request
        req_get.setEndpoint(endpoint_get + resource_get);
        req_get.setMethod(method_get);

        // Do the HTTP get request
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);

        String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);

        req_get.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);            

        req_get.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');



       try{
        // Perform callout and set response
        res_get = h_get.send(req_get);

        // check response 
        if ((res_get.getStatusCode() == 200 || res_get.getStatusCode() == 201) && res_get.getBody() != null && res_get.getBody() != null) {

            System.debug(res_get);

              // Deserialize the response untyped
              Map<String, Object> untypedMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res_get.getBody());


                // Check success of deserialization
                if(untypedMap.containsKey('results')){

                        // The deserialized response contains the expected key

                        JSONGenerator jGenerator = JSON.createGenerator(true); 
                        jGenerator.writeFieldName('ticket');
                        jGenerator.writeStartObject();
                        jGenerator.writeFieldName('comment');  
                        jGenerator.writeStartObject();
                        jGenerator.writeObjectField('body', data_comment);     
                        jGenerator.writeEndObject();
                        jGenerator.writeEndObject(); 
                        jGenerator.writeEndObject();     
                        String jGeneratorString = jGenerator.getAsString();
                        System.debug('jsonMaterials'+jGeneratorString);

                        // create the put request to the WA server
                        HttpRequest req_put = new HttpRequest();

                        req_put.setEndpoint(endpoint_put + resource_put);
                        req_put.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader); 
                        req_put.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
                        req_put.setMethod(method_put);
                        req_put.setBody(jGeneratorString);

                        Http h_put = new Http();
                        HttpResponse res_put = h_put.send(req_put);

                        system.debug('Response' + res_put);
                        system.debug('notification id ' + res_put.getBody());
                    }  else {
                        outcomeMsg = 'Error: Verify key not found in response';
                        }
                    } 
            }   catch (exception e) {
                    // Unexpected exceptions will be caught here, like a deserialization error.
                    outcomeMsg = 'Error: An exception has been encountered while calling out to Integration:  ' + e.getMessage();
                }
            }

    // Return the response
    return outcomeMsg;
}
```

This part keeps giving me this error message `System.JSONException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value`

```
                JSONGenerator jGenerator = JSON.createGenerator(true); 
                jGenerator.writeFieldName('ticket');
                jGenerator.writeStartObject();
                jGenerator.writeFieldName('comment');  
                jGenerator.writeStartObject();
                jGenerator.writeObjectField('body', data_comment);     
                jGenerator.writeEndObject();
                jGenerator.writeEndObject(); 
                jGenerator.writeEndObject();     
                String jGeneratorString = jGenerator.getAsString();
                System.debug('jsonMaterials'+jGeneratorString);
```

Can anyone help me me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writting a field name without starting the object. Try adding a `writeStartObject()` just after creting the generator. Something like:

```
JSONGenerator jGenerator = JSON.createGenerator(true); 
jGenerator.writeStartObject(); // adding this line
jGenerator.writeFieldName('ticket');
jGenerator.writeStartObject();
jGenerator.writeFieldName('comment');
```

For more information check the [JSON Generator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm) chapter of the Developer Guide.